# ODE with non-differentiable RHS: "Filippov solver"?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, math-software, lipschitz-functions

I've a differential system $\dot{x}=F(x)$ where $F:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$ is bounded, non-differentiable on a countable set of points and Lipschitz elsewhere. This should imply that solutions (in the sense of Filippov) are absolutely continuous.

I'm looking for a software able to simulate these trajectories, as I noticed that Matlab, which works fine when F is Lipschitz, fails. Does anybody know what can I use to simulate this system?

Comment: How does matlab fail? Did you try to get exact switching by using events to restart at the singular (in the sense of non-regular) points?

Comment: It gets stuck at the first encountered point of non-differentiability (met on a boundary). Then, after a while, somehow the solver exits from it but takes a path that does not make any sense: I'm sure that that path is not a correct one, I think there is some numerical instability in the solver.  I tried almost all solvers given by matlab and all of them don't seem to be able to handle even the first singularity correctly.

Comment: A solver of order $p$ with an embedded method of order $p+1$ for step size control assumes that the ODE is $p+1$ times continuously differentiable. So it is best to constrain the solver to pieces of the solution where this assumption is satisfied. -- Can you make a typical but small example of your problem class?

Comment: Non-differentiability points appear on the boundaries, where Lipschitz and bounded terms are multiplied by indicator functions saying whether the trajectory touches or not the boundary.
I will try to apply what you wrote but before I need to find those intervals and it may not be simple!

Answer (score 0):

Try DISODE45. The group of researchers have come up with a matlab function that helps you solve the problem you are describing and they have good documentation on how to use it as well.

Here's the link you might find useful.

https://iuma.unizar.es/es/investigacion/software/disode45

Disclaimer : I am not the author of this code and take no credit for it. I simply came across this while working on my own research and found it useful.